# an integer is required, chr defined

Tags: python, integer, typeerror, chr

The line of error given is:

```
letter = chr(input('Enter a letter')).lower()
```

and the output I recieve is:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Is there something that I didn't put? I think since I
have chr() it should require any single character.

Comment: Do you know what `chr` does? http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#chr It converts an integer to it's ASCII character representation.

Comment: @leetNightshade: This is most probably Python 3, where `chr()` produces any legal Unicode codepoint from an integer.

Comment: Python does not have compulsory explicit typing. More importantly, it does not have a 'character' datatype as such, only one-length strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chr()` requires an integer, but `input()` returns a string. Just remove the `chr()` call:

```
letter = input('Enter a letter').lower()
```

If you wanted to limit the input to just one character, use slicing:

```
letter = input('Enter a letter')[:1].lower()
```

Python doesn't have a 'single character' type.

`chr()` is only used to turn an integer code point into a (single character) string:

```
>>> chr(65)
'A'
```

Comment: Yeah, I think OP comes from a programming background with more explicit typing, such as C.